# Dynamic select list using SQL data

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

I am trying to create a select drop-down list using php. Every time i try, i get an error.
Here is my code:

The function:

```
function dropDown(){
    $options="<select>"; 
    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','id','pass') or die ("couldn't   connect!").mysql_error; 

    mysql_select_db('db') or die('could not connect to database!');

    $sql="SELECT * FROM DESC"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // this is line 60
        $name=$row["name"]; 
    
        $options.="<option value=\"$name\">".$name."</option>"; 
    } 

    $options.= "</SELECT>";
    return "$options";
}
```

and then i just call it in my code

```
<?php  
include ('includes/functions.php');

// ...

$list = dropDown();
echo "$list";

// ...

?>
```

The error I get is:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/garagenj/public_html/dispatch/includes/functions.php on line 60
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/garagenj/public_html/dispatch/includes/functions.php on line 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table name *is* `DESC` then that's your problem.  It's all about namespacing.  You can't even have a field named `desc`, I've tried.  It errors everytime

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.  I had a field named `desc` for description.  took me awhile to track it down too before I pulled a Homer Simpson... **DOH**

Comment: same here, I will accept your answer once it allows me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Either your table is using a reserved word (desc) or your query is all jacked up. Try this:

`select * from table order by col desc`

Be sure to replace `table` and `col` with your table name and column name.

Answer (score 0):

### SELECT * FROM DESC ??????

- From what table
- Or, if the table name is DESC. escape them with ticks

---

And You dont have start a new connection, every time you call the function. Put your connection part somewhere else

```
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','id','pass') or die ("couldn't   connect!").mysql_error; 
mysql_select_db('db') or die('could not connect to database!');

function dropDown(){
    $options="<select>"; 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `DESC`"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql); 
    
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    
        $name=$row["name"]; 
    
        $options.="<option value=\"$name\">".$name."</option>"; 
    } 
    
    $options.= "</SELECT>";
    return $options;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM DESC";
```

You forgot to add the table name to select from

Comment: the table name is DESC, sorry for not being clear, is it a reserved function in sql? should i change its name?